# Android: Notif push (FCM) doesn't receive properly when App is in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've updated from 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4' to '10.2.6', and since all notification push receive when my App is in background, don't catch in **onMessageReceived()**.

On the official documentation (https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) I don't see informations about this.

Ps: in 10.2.4, all worked perfectly.

Could you help guys?

Comment: Hi anthony. Are you seeing any error response when you send the message? How are you sending the message (console or own App server)? Could you also post your `onMessageReceived()` code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the `onMessageReceived` in all cases you cannot use `notification` push messages. You can only use `data` payload in your FCM messages.

> `onMessageReceived` is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:
>
> **Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background.** In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
>
> **Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground.** In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Eugen, in 10.2.4 all worked perfectly; I've just updated to 10.2.6 (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging) and the behavior in background is different now. I use "data" payload and not "notification". Thanks!

Comment: @anthony I see... If you reinstall the app and it works, it may be a token problem. If that's not the case you should report a bug on Android Issue tracker.

Comment: no there is no change (after reinstallation); I've tested with postman: it works perfectly even if the App is in background; but from my server side, there is this problem (and it's the same data sent!). I don't understand